# Updated example of using Stact

Tags: .net, topshelf, actor-model

I see many references to using [Stact](https://github.com/phatboyg/Stact) to implement ActorModel in C#. But I don't see any recent examples, and the documentation makes it hard to figure out what is the pit of success (which is unfortunate because TopShelf and MassTransit both have decent documentation). Are there any updated usage examples that go past the simple Receive examples, an integrate with something like an IoC container to create concrete Actor classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Riktig](https://github.com/phatboyg/Riktig) is likely the best example of everything built on Stact. [Cashbox](https://github.com/travisthetechie/Cashbox) is written on an older version of Stact and isn't a very big codebase, so might be a place to start.

Stact mostly exists so we can build the other cool stuff. [Akka.net](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/) might be a better solution if you want full blown actors - though I've never used it. They are more interested in supporting an ecosystem around the library than Stact has gathered to this point. Unless they are hidden from me, which is possible.